# LWJGL - Getting error : "Cannot use offsets when Element Array Buffer Object is disabled"

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, arraybuffer

I am trying to render a basic cube in LWJGL (Java). But the program keeps crashing, telling me that it "Cannot use offsets when Element Array Buffer Object is disabled". I am guessing that this is not the exact error right here and there might be something less obvious than that.

(I actually did the code that I'm about to show you in C++ and it was working very fine)

Init function (called once)

```
FloatBuffer vertices = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4 * 5);
vertices.put(new float[]{
    // pos                  // Color
    0.5f, 0.5f,             1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,            0.5f, 0.0f, 0.75f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,           0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f,            0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f
});
vertices.flip();

indices = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(2 * 3);
indices.put(new byte[]{
    0, 1, 3,
    1, 2, 3
});
indices.flip();
    
// VAO
VAO = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
GL30.glBindVertexArray(VAO);

// VBO
VBO = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// IBO
IBO = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
//                    ,-- position in layout (see shader)
//                    |  ,-- Nb of component per vertex (2 for 2D (x, y))
//                    |  |                 ,-- Normalized ? (between 0 - 1)
//                    |  |                 |      ,-- Offset between things (size of a line)
//                    |  |                 |      |                ,- Where to start ?
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * Float.SIZE , 0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * Float.SIZE , 2 * Float.SIZE);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);

// Unbinds the VAO
GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
```

And here is the render function (static for now, until I figure this out)

```
glUseProgram(shaderProgram.getID());

GL30.glBindVertexArray(VAO);

// Error in the line bellow
GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 4, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
```

A little help would be very appreciated. Also, I might be something very wrong that I'm not aware of, so if you spot something that would be awesome.

Thank you

---

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 color;

out vec4 Color;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    Color = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Framgent Shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec4 Color;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = Color;
}
```

Comment: You need to `glEnableVertexAttribArray(Vertices index);`
before calling the `drawElements(...);`
and then disable it.

Comment: No. That is handled by the VAO.

Comment: the last bind buffer should be to GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,

Comment: That error message is ***Terrible***. I'm pretty sure what it means to say is that if there's nothing bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, you can't use **0** for the offset (that would dereference a NULL pointer). You can't enable or disable an element array buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines

```
IBO = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

are creating a new array buffer. from the name you choose and the data you copy to, I guess this is your index buffer and thus should be of type GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER.

What the error message is telling you is, that you draw command cannot use 0 as offset into your index buffer if there is non.

**Why is there nothing drawn after fixing the index buffer?**

Problem 1: You are only drawing 4 indices. If you want to draw 2 triangles, you will need 6 indices.

Problem 2: OpenGL is a statemachine and VAOs only store the last state that was set when they are unbound. This means your calls to glDisableVertexAttribArray will disable the attributes for your VAO. You should move this calls after GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

Comment: Thank you very much. At least now it's not crashing.

But now, it's not rendering anything. I might have messed up somewhere else.

Is the VAO still needed, I wonder ?

Comment: Yes, unless you are in OpenGL < 3.3 Core and want to bind all buffers each time you draw. Starting from OpenGL 3.3 Core it is mandatory to use VAOs.

Comment: I already fixed that on my own but no change. I'm guessing the error comes from the glVertexAttribPointer as I'm using the "C++ way" that I learned. I'm not sure if it's the same way in Java

Comment: And also, I know that I can actually draw things. I tried with glBegin(GL_QUADS) and it was working as expected

Comment: I tried your solutions, that didn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: I'm not sure anymore how the current state of your code looks like. It may be good to ask another question about why you don't get anything drawn, including the current version.